# Conditional expression cannot be determined, multiplying Eval by number

Tags: .net, conditional-statements

We are trying to multiply an Eval by an integer. Within the hidden field costPass. We keep receiving an error that conditional expressions cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between int and string. If I remove the conditional expression within costPass and leave Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DeliveryTime")) * 2 or 5 the value is correct. Why is this not working within the conditional expression?

```
 <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("MaxNumber")) <= Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Enrolled")) ? 
 "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type='button' disabled><b>FULL</b>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " + Eval("BeginDate", "{0 :MMMMMMMM dd, yyyy}") + 
 " - " + Eval("EndDate", "{0 :MMMMMMMM dd, yyyy}") + "</button>" : 
 "<form action='/register2.asp' method='post'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type='hidden' name='sID' value='" + Eval("SectionID") + "'>
 <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='" + Session["BeaconLogin"] + "'>
 <input type='hidden' ID='costPass' name='costPass' 
 value='" + Eval("ShortCourse") == "Y" ? 
 Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DeliveryTime")) * 2 : 
 Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DeliveryTime")) * 5 + "' 
 runat='server'><input type='submit' value='Register - " + Eval("BeginDate", 
 "{0 :MMMMMMMM dd, yyyy}") + " - " + Eval("EndDate", "{0 :MMMMMMMM dd, yyyy}") + 
 "' style='width:300px;'></form>"%>
```

**Code Intent/Clarification**

The entire snippet is used within a child repeater in .Net.

Using a mixture of C# and HTML within .Net, the code starts by comparing MaxNumber and Enrolled, both are DB columns with Enrolled being calculated within the SELECT statement. If MaxNumber is less than or equal to Enrolled the user sees a disabled FULL button. Else, the user sees a REGISTER button with the BeginDate and EndDate of that section. The child repeater writes each section as a separate REGISTER button.

Each REGISTER button has form data attached. Passing variables to this form was not working correctly so that's why this portion is written this way. First, hidden field sID is created with SectionID being the value, then hidden field ID with the Session variable as it's value pulling the users ID given when they log in. Let's skip costPass for now, last portion is the submit button that has the value REGISTER - BeginDate - EndDate. BeginDate and EndDate are formatted to show Month day, year.

The piece causing problems, costPass is a hidden field. The value of costPass compares the DB column ShortCourse to "Y". If ShortCourse equals then DB column DeliveryTime is converted to int32 and multiplied by 2 else that DeliveryTime is multiplied by 5.

**EDIT/FIX:**
Added parentheses, as suggested, and changed a portion of the costPass value (see code).

```
  (Eval("ShortCourse").Equals("Y") ? (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DeliveryTime")) * 2) 
  : (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DeliveryTime")) * 5))
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing in that messy code, but the problem is probably operator precedence. Try adding parentheses to make your intent clear.

Comment: This code is from within a nested repeater on a .net page.

Comment: That's no excuse for writing unreadable code. Please tag the question with the language.

Comment: That's not an excuse it's just an answer to your question, "What language is this". I just forgot to add that when submitting the question. No worries though, I have it fixed now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED:** 
Added parentheses, as suggested, and changed a portion of the costPass value (see code).

```
  (Eval("ShortCourse").Equals("Y") ? (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DeliveryTime")) * 2) 
  : (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DeliveryTime")) * 5))
```